# Change XML tags within PowerShell and keep content.

Tags: xml, regex, powershell, replace

I have exported data from an EventLog using PowerShell and have created a sample Schema to import the data into SQL however there is an issue of the way the data is exported from PowerShell using ConvertToXML.

The exports of the XML looks like this;

```
<Property Name="Version">0</Property>

<Property Name="Qualifiers" />

<Property Name="Level">0</Property>

<Property Name="Task">14339</Property>

<Property Name="Opcode">0</Property>

<Property Name="Keywords">-9218868437227405312</Property>

<Property Name="RecordId">57963203</Property>

<Property Name="ProviderName">Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing</Property>
```

But it should look something like this;

```
<Version>0</Version>

<Qualifiers> />

<Level>0</Level>

<Task>14339</Task>
```

The code below identifies the start and end of the property name version and property tag
and attempts to change it to but unfortunately it changes it without keeping the contents within the tag. I can't seem to kept the value.

```
$EventLog = (Get-WinEvent -ComputerName xxxxxxx-FilterXML $Query) | ConvertTo-Xml -NoTypeInformation

$EventLogModify = (Get-Content P:\EventTracking\Events.xml) | foreach{$_ -replace '(<Property Name=""Version"">(.*?)</Property>)', "<Version></Version>" };Set-Content P:\EventTracking\Events.xml $EventLogModify;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in

```
-replace '(<Property Name=""Version"">(.*?)</Property>)', "<Version></Version>"
```

You replace a complete tag by an empty tag. I guess you want to use the captured group in the replacement:

```
-replace '(<Property Name=""Version"">(.*?)</Property>)', '<Version>$2</Version>'
```

Furthermore you probably used double quotes on the regex before, because there are `""` in there. This likely won't match anything because it now looks for two double quotes in a row.

Another thing, you probably want to replace all at once, so use this maybe:

```
-replace '<Property Name="([^"]+)">([^<]+)</Property>', '<$1>$2</$1>'
```

That's not really enough, though:

```
PS> $xml -replace '<Property Name="([^"]+)">([^<]+)</Property>', '<$1>$2</$1>'
<Version>0</Version>
<Property Name="Qualifiers" />
<Level>0</Level>
<Task>14339</Task>
<Opcode>0</Opcode>
<Keywords>-9218868437227405312</Keywords>
<RecordId>57963203</RecordId>
<ProviderName>Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing</ProviderName>
```

As you can see, `Qualifiers` is still not changed. So another replace:

```
-replace '<Property Name="([^"]+)"\s*/>','<$1/>'
```

Looks better now

```
PS> $xml -replace '<Property Name="([^"]+)">([^<]+)</Property>', '<$1>$2</$1>' -replace '<Property Name="([^"]+)"\s*/>','<$1/>'
<Version>0</Version>
<Qualifiers/>
<Level>0</Level>
<Task>14339</Task>
<Opcode>0</Opcode>
<Keywords>-9218868437227405312</Keywords>
<RecordId>57963203</RecordId>
<ProviderName>Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing</ProviderName>
```

Comment: Wow. That is absolutely beautiful. This is my code now; 

$EventLogModify = (Get-Content P:\EventTracking\Events.xml) | foreach{$_ -replace '<Property Name="([^"]+)">([^<]+)</Property>', '<$1>$2</$1>' -replace '<Property Name="([^"]+)"\s*/>','<$1/>' };Set-Content P:\EventTracking\Events.xml $EventLogModify;

Thank you so much.

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic. Thank you very much. 

This is my final code;

Comment: Well, the proper way would *probably* be to use the XML APIs, but since what you have there is not actually XML that's a bit tricky. Essentially you'd have to surround the snippet with another tag, parse it all as XML, make the transformations of atributes to element names in the DOM and write it as XML again, afterwards stripping it of the now superfluous surrounding tag. Not nice, not fun, but probably safer than using regexes (though I thi'nk what you're doing there is safe enough).

Answer (score 0):

another simple way:

```
[Xml]$xml=@'
<root>
<Property Name="Version">0</Property>
<Property Name="Qualifiers" />
<Property Name="Level">0</Property>
<Property Name="Task">14339</Property>
<Property Name="Opcode">0</Property>
<Property Name="Keywords">-9218868437227405312</Property>
<Property Name="RecordId">57963203</Property>
<Property Name="ProviderName">Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing</Property>
</root>
'@



$xml.SelectNodes('//Property') | ForEach `
 -begin { 
       $h = New-Object xml
       $r = $h.CreateElement("ROOT")
       $null=$h.AppendChild($r)
   } `
 -process {
     if($_.'#text') {
         $n = $h.CreateElement($_.Name)
         $n.InnerText = $_.'#text'
         $null=$r.AppendChild($n)
     }
     else {
        $n = $h.CreateElement($_.Name)
        $null=$r.AppendChild($n)
      }
    } `
 -End {
      $h.OuterXml
      }
```

or:

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//Property')|% {
if($_.'#text') { "<{0}>{1}</{0}>" -f $_.name,$_.'#text' } else {"<$($_.name)/>"}
}
```