# Powershell convert json string to xml string always produces System.String

Tags: json, xml, string, powershell

I searched a lot and tried a lot but I didnt get the point.

my json string`{"transactionId":411648956,"status":1123}`
always converts to

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Objects> <Object Type="System.String">{"transactionId":411648956,"status":1123}</Object> </Objects>`

<Object> just contains my string but no xml.

I would like to have this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <status>1123</status>
   <transactionId>411648956</transactionId>
</root>
```

Here is some code I tried but without success

```
 $jsonline = '{"transactionId":411648956,"status":1123}'
 echo 1--------- $jsonline

 $xmlline = ConvertTo-Xml -as String $jsonline -Depth 3
 echo 5--------- $xmlline

 $jsonobj =  ConvertTo-Json $jsonline  -Depth 3
 echo 10--------- $jsonobj

 $xmlline2 = ConvertTo-Xml -as String $jsonobj -Depth 3
 echo 15--------- $xmlline2

 $jsonobj2 = $jsonline | ConvertTo-Json
 echo 20--------- $jsonobj2 

 $xmlline3 = ConvertTo-Xml -as string -InputObject $jsonobj2 -Depth 10
 echo 25--------- $xmlline3
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `$jsonline` is a string, not a json object as such. You need to convert it to an object before converting to xml:

```bsh
$jsonline = '{"transactionId":411648956,"status":1123}'
$json = ConvertFrom-Json $jsonline
[xml] $xml =  ConvertTo-Xml -InputObject $json -As Document -NoTypeInformation
```

The `-NoTypeInformation` parameter gets rid of your string object thing.

After that you either need some xml manipulation, some xsl or some nasty text manipulation to get the tag names you want. I will show the nasty text manipulation:

```bsh
$result = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>`n<root>"
$result+= $xml.SelectNodes('//Property')|% {
    if($_.'#text') { "`n`t<{0}>{1}</{0}>" -f $_.name,$_.'#text' } else {"<$($_.name)/>"}
}
$result+="`n</root>"
$result
```

I select the nodes and turn their property name into the tag name. The code is inspired by @Walid2mi's answer to this question: [Change XML tags within PowerShell and keep content.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517524/change-xml-tags-within-powershell-and-keep-content).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Palle Due.
Yes the point is to use ConvertFrom-Json.
Here is my solution:

```
    <# Solution to convert json to pretty xml
based on https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/7en74l/json_to_xml_and_back/
using https://github.com/omrsafetyo/PowerShellSnippets/blob/master/Convert-CustomObjectToXml.ps1
#>


Function Convert-CustomObjectToXml {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
 
Outputs a human readable simple text XML representation of a simple PS object.
 
.PARAMETER object
 
The input object to inspect and dump.
 
.PARAMETER depth
 
The number of levels deep to dump. Defaults to 1.
 
.PARAMETER rootEl
 
The name of the root element in the document. Defaults to "root"
 
.PARAMETER indentString
 
The string used to indent each level of XML. Defaults to two spaces.
Set to "" to remove indentation.
 
.DESCRIPTION
 
Outputs a human readable simple text XML representation of a simple PS object.
 
A PSObject with member types of NoteProperty will be dumped to XML.  Only
nested PSObjects up to the depth specified will be searched. All other
note properties will be ouput using their strings values.
 
The output consists of node with property names and text nodes containing the
property value.
Original Author: http://wannemacher.us/?p=430
Modified to include working with Object arrays, and now outputs XML instead of strings.
 
#>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [PSCustomObject]$object,
        [Int32]$depth = 1,
        [String]$rootEl = "root",
        [String]$indentString = "  ",
        [Int32]$indent = 1,
        [switch]$isRoot = $true,
        [String]$XmlVersion = "1.0",
        [String]$Encoding = "UTF-8"
    )
    BEGIN {
        $sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
    }
    
    PROCESS {
        # Output the root element opening tag
        if ($isRoot) {
            [void]$sb.AppendLine(("<{0}>" -f $rootEl))
        }
        
        ForEach ( $item in $object ) {
            # Iterate through all of the note properties in the object.
            foreach ($prop in (Get-Member -InputObject $item -MemberType NoteProperty)) {
                $children = $item.($prop.Name)
                foreach ($child in $children) {
                    # Check if the property is an object and we want to dig into it
                    if ($child.GetType().Name -eq "PSCustomObject" -and $depth -gt 1) {
                        [void]$sb.AppendLine(("{0}<{1}>" -f ($indentString * $indent), $prop.Name))
                        Convert-CustomObjectToXml $child -isRoot:$false -indent ($indent + 1) -depth ($depth - 1) -indentString $indentString | ForEach-Object { [void]$sb.AppendLine($_) }
                        [void]$sb.AppendLine(("{0}</{1}>" -f ($indentString * $indent), $prop.Name))
                    }
                    else {
                        # output the element or elements in the case of an array
                        foreach ($element in $child) {
                            [void]$sb.AppendLine(("{0}<{1}>{2}</{1}>" -f ($indentString * $indent), $prop.Name, $element))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     
        # If this is the root, close the root element and convert it to Xml and output
        if ($isRoot) {
            [void]$sb.AppendLine(("</{0}>" -f $rootEl))
            [xml]$Output = $sb.ToString()
            $xmlDeclaration = $Output.CreateXmlDeclaration($XmlVersion,$Encoding,$null)
            [void]$Output.InsertBefore($xmlDeclaration, $Output.DocumentElement)
            $Output
        }
        else {
            # If this is the not the root, this has been called recursively, output the string
            Write-Output $sb.ToString()
        }
    }
    END {}
}

# make json string to object
$jsonline = '{"transactionId":411648956,"status":"OK"}'
$jsonObject = ConvertFrom-Json –InputObject  $jsonline  
echo $jsonObject
echo ---------------------------


# make object to xml 
$xml = Convert-CustomObjectToXml -object $jsonObject -depth 99 
echo  $xml.OuterXml

# save xml with pretty print
$xml.Save("C:\tmp\test.xml")
```